# Как развернуть веб интерфейс модема Huawei?

Tags: веб-программирование, сборка

Есть веб интерфейс, взятый из прошивки модема Huawei. Он представляет собой такую структуру : 
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как собрать и развернуть его, чтобы все выглядело как при запуске самого модема ? Пробовал делать фронтенд сборку, пробовал запустить через локальный сервер - ничего не выходит.

Comment: Что у вас пока получилось? Добавте ваш код прямо в вопрос.

Comment: Не знаю, какой код, пока я попробовал запустить через openserver - открывается просто пустое окно. При этом выпадает много ошибок, то что не удаётся подключить скрипты. 
http://prntscr.com/hfjz9c